# How can i change Switch buttons behavior

Tags: android, listener, android-button

I'm new with `Android` and I have a problems with switch buttons.
I want to switch button, but not change state on tapping (as if it was with `CheckBox`) but only dragging it.
Is possible to disable the tapping listener or maybe I have to work with `OnTouchListener()` and `OnDragListener()` interfaces and create a switch button?

I try to override methods :

```
final Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTest);
mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
 @Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
}
});
```

i try also :

```
mySwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

in onCreate method and also :

```
android:clickable="false"
```

in xml file don't work

Comment: Try this link http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-disable-state-change-event-on-click-in-android-switch-button-i-need-to-drag-event-only/

Comment: Extend the standard switch and override the appropriate method(s). I wouldn't recommend what you want to do though, as some people (me included) usually click on it instead of drag it (specially if dragging can also swipe to next fragment).